# If $\rm AX = XB$ for any $\rm X$ of constant dims $m \times n$, then does $\rm A$ exists for given $\rm B$ and how to find it?

Tags: matrices, terminology, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

> What is the name of matrix $\rm A$ with respect to matrix $\rm B$ so that
>   $$\rm AX = XB$$
>   for any $\rm X$?
>
> Does this matrix exist? How to find it?

Comment: "Does this matrix exist?" - Which one do you mean? Which matrices are given? Only $A$, only $B$ or both?

Comment: $B$ is given, $X$ is any.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it's not me who changed the title

Comment: @DietrichBurde now I changed it to closer to what I meant

Comment: All right, it might be a language problem. Do you mean $AX=XB$ for **some** $X$, or for **all** $X$? I don't know what "any" means here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry, for all $X$ of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you can always take $X = I$, so always $A = B$; and the only matrices $A,B$ which satisfy this are $A = B = \alpha I$, where $\alpha$ is any scalar.

Comment: I was thinking matrices are not square. Was this impossible assumption?

Comment: For non-square matrices, $AX$ and $XB$ may have different sizes. Then there is no solution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde may have or will have different size?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hmmm, title is something different, the question was about properties and existence of $A$

Answer (score 1):

The equation is a special case of the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)
$$
AX+XB=C,
$$
where we could write $-B$ instead of $B$. Here $A,B,C$ are given, and we look for solutions $X$ (as we usually do for equations). In your case, however, you only have given $B$, and you want the equation to hold for all $X$. This restricts the possibilities to find a matrix $A$ severely. If all matrices are square, then taking $X=I$ yields $A=B$, and both equal to a scalar multiple of the identity.

Edit: If it is meant that $AX=XB$ for *some* $X$, then you can solve the Sylvester equation to find an $X$, see wikipedia and its links.